# php wordpress get_the_post_thumbnail - array issue (probably easy fix)

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically the format of the image tag I am trying to create is:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" class="attachment-catalog" data-src="my/image/path/here">
```

And here is my code:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        $newimgdetails = array(
                            'src'      => "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=",
                            'class'    => "attachment-$size",
                            'alt'      => trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt ) ),
                            'title'    => trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ) ),
                            'data-src' => $src,
                          );    
        echo  get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'shop_catalog', $newimgdetails);
    }
?>
```

I'm fairly new to php so I'm assuming it's an easy fix, but I've been messing around with this for the past hour.

Can someone help me get this one figured out?

Here is a link to the codex for get_the_post_thumbnail - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

*Update - Tried this code out with a picture from google and it works. The issue is my variable `$src`. I need this to get the path to the image, which it is currently not doing. I used $src because I saw it in the codex link above and thought it would work. lol.

Comment: Not sure if you can use 'shop_catalog' as the second parameter of the get_the_post_thumbnail() function. Thought that had to be one of an array of predefined values (thumbnail, medium, large, or full) or an array specifying a size.

Comment: I think my theme adds another value. It was already being used when I began customizing

Answer (score 0):

I am asuming that you have registered 'shop_catalog' using [add_image_size](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
        $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'shop_catalog', true);
        $src = $thumb_url_array[0];

        echo '<img scr="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" class="attachment-catalog" alt="'.trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt ) ).'" title="'.trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ) ).'" data-src="'.$src.'">';
    }
?>
```